# UserRepresentation can not be extracted from Keycloak UserRepresentation (HTTP 404 Not Found Exception)

Tags: security, spring-boot, servlets, servlet-filters, keycloak

I am very new to Keycloak usage. Based on the documentation I started playing around with Keycloak API.

I am getting Http 404 not found exception when i use the API **userResource.toRepresentation()** to get the details about the specific user.

```
import org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.RealmResource;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.UserResource;
import org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation;

public class Snippet_authorization {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Keycloak kc = Keycloak.getInstance(
                "http://localhost:8080/auth",
                "master",
                "admin",
                "password",
                "admin-cli");

        RealmResource realm = kc.realm("SpringBootKeyCloak");

        UserResource userResource = realm.users().get("testuser");

        UserRepresentation user = userResource.toRepresentation();


        kc.close();


    }

}
```

Below is the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:200)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:171)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.BodyEntityExtractor.extractEntity(BodyEntityExtractor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:104)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.toRepresentation(Unknown Source)
    at kc.Snippet_authorization.main(Snippet_authorization.java:21)
```

I found that similar issue was already posted, but there is no solution yet.

http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-January/009069.html

I will be thankful if you can provide me solution here

Comment: Can you share realm information, which have created in Keycloak admin and server port

Comment: I hope you have keycloak-admin-client jar in pom dependency

Comment: just now I learnt that that, In API "UserResource userResource = realm.users().get("testuser");" instead of a userID, i should provide UUID which is in the following format : " da0e2bcd-3768-4ff5-b315-c3cc09830a63". with this change, API access looks like UserResource userResource = realm.users().get("da0e2bcd-3768-4ff5-b315-c3cc09830a63"); and this is working fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting user keycloak Not Found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593531/getting-user-keycloak-not-found-exception)

Comment: @ZaksM thanks for your comment about user UUID, it helped me a lot, great hint!